# Queue interface

Tags: c, pointers, queue, doubly-linked-list

I have to implement a FIFO queue interface for a bigger project.
The queue needs to work with any type of data, so I decided to use `void*` pointers as value for the nodes of my queue, and to use a double linked list. Each node has a `value`, a `prev` and a `next`.

For better understanding, please note that `front` refers to the first node in the queue, and `back` is the last-added node.

I wrote an `enqueue` and a `dequeue` function, and also a `peek_back` and a `peek_front function`.

However, it looks like something's wrong when I run some tests within my `main()` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "queue.h"

int main(){

    queue_t* q = init_queue();
    if(q == NULL){
        printf("Error: q not initialized properly\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //Test with a struct
    struct point {
       int    x;
       int    y;
    };

    for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
        struct point p = {i,i};
        struct point* p_ptr = &p;
        enqueue(q, (void*) p_ptr);
        printf("One node added, front value: %i, back value: %i\n", ((struct point*)peek_front(q))->x, ((struct point*)peek_back(q))->x);
    }

    int result;
    int size;
    while(q->size > 0){
        result = *(int*) dequeue(q);
        size = q->size;
        printf("One node removed, value = %i. Size is now %i \n", result, size);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
gcc main.c queue.c -o main.o -Wall -Werror
./main.o
One node added, front value: 1, back value: 1
One node added, front value: 2, back value: 2
One node added, front value: 3, back value: 3
One node removed, value = 3. Size is now 2 
One node removed, value = 3. Size is now 1 
One node removed, value = 3. Size is now 0
```

As you see, `enqueue` changes the front node of my queue, although it shouldn't, and `dequeue` always return the same value...

Do you have any idea where the problem might come from ? I tried to debug with gdb but I'm really struggling to spot the problem. Also, I'd be glad to hear your feedback about the general implementation of this queue... Any advice is welcome, as I am only a beginner in C ;)

Here's my `queue.h`header file:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H


typedef struct node{
  struct node* next;
  struct node* prev;
  void* value;
} node_t;

typedef struct queue{
  struct node* front;
  struct node* back;
  int size;
} queue_t;

queue_t* init_queue();
int enqueue(queue_t* q, void* val);
void* dequeue(queue_t* q);
int get_size(queue_t* q);
int is_empty(queue_t * q);
void* peek_front(queue_t * q);
void* peek_back(queue_t * q);

#endif
```

And here's my `queue.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "queue.h"

/*
 * Allocate memory and initialize a new queue with size = 0 and front = NULL
 * @return: initialized queue if succes, NULL if failed malloc
 */
queue_t* init_queue(){
    queue_t* newQueue = (queue_t*)malloc(sizeof(queue_t));
    if(!newQueue){
        printf("Malloc error in init_queue\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    newQueue->front = NULL;
    newQueue->back = NULL;
    newQueue->size = 0;

    return newQueue;
}

/*
 * Add a new node with value @val at the end (back) of the queue @q
 * @q: a valid queue (queue_t type)
 * @val: the value to be added
 * return 0 if success, -1 if failure
 */
int enqueue(queue_t* q, void* val){
    struct node *newNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(!newNode) return  -1;
    newNode->value = val;

    if(q->size == 0){
        newNode->next = newNode;
        newNode->prev = newNode;
        q->front = newNode;
        q->back = newNode;
    }
    else{
        newNode->next = q->back;
        newNode->prev = q->front;
        q->back->prev = newNode;
        q->front->next = newNode;
        q->back = newNode;
    }

    q->size ++;

    return 0;
}

/*
 * Remove front node of queue @q and return its value
 * @q: a valid queue
 * @return: value of removed front node (int) if success
 *          NULL if empty queue
 */
void* dequeue(queue_t* q){
    if(q->size == 0){
        printf("Warning: empty queue\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    void* tbr = q->front->value; //to be returned

    if(q->size == 1){
        free(q->front);
        q->front = NULL;
    }else{
        struct node * old_front = q->front;
        old_front->prev->next = q->back;
        q->back->prev = old_front->prev;
        q->front = old_front->prev;
    }
    q->size--;

    return tbr;
}

/*
 * @q: a valid queue
 * @return: size of queue @q if q is not NULL
 *          -1 if q is NULL
 */
int get_size(queue_t* q){
    if(q != NULL){
        return q->size;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}

/* 
 * Check wether @q is empty or not
 * @q: a valid queue
 * @return: 1 if @q is empty, 0 otherwise
 */
int is_empty(queue_t * q){
    return get_size(q) == 0;
}

/*
 * Peek the value of front node of queue @q, but doesn't remove it
 * @q: a valid queue
 * @return: value of front node
 */
void* peek_front(queue_t * q){
    if (q->size == 0){
        printf("Peeking an empty queue\n");
        return NULL;
    }else{
        return q->front->value;
    }
}

/*
 * Peek the value of last node (last added, back of the tail) 
 * from queue @q, but doesn't remove it
 * @q: a valid queue
 * @return: value of last-added node (back)
 */
void* peek_back(queue_t * q){
    if (q->size == 0){
        printf("Peeking an empty queue\n");
        return NULL;
    }else{
        return q->back->value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, especially when storing just pointers.

Comment: Note: "needs to work with any type of data, so I decided to use `void*` pointers" --> A `void*` can covert to/from _object_ pointers faithfully.  `void*`  to/from _function_ pointers.  is not certain.

Comment: In the .h file, `typedef struct node{
  struct node* next;
  struct node* prev;
  void* value;
} node_t;` and `typedef struct queue{
  struct node* front;
  struct node* back;
  int size;
} queue_t;` not needed.  Only need `typedef struct queue queue_t;`.  In the .c file, put the `struct` definitions.  (Information hiding)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica if I do so I get this error when I compile:
`main.c: In function ‘test_struct’: main.c:54:9: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘queue_t’ {aka ‘struct queue’}`
at line 
`54 |  while(q->size > 0){`

Comment: @DiegoH `main` should not use `q->size`.  Instead, use `get_size(q)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main()` you're doing this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    struct point p = {i,i};    // HERE : automatic local inside loop
    struct point* p_ptr = &p;  // HERE : acquire the address of that local var
    enqueue(q, (void*) p_ptr); // HERE : store said address in the queue
    printf("One node added, front value: %i, back value: %i\n", ((struct point*)peek_front(q))->x, ((struct point*)peek_back(q))->x);
} // HERE : address stored is no longer valid.
```

Dynamic allocation is one solution, and fairly easy. Sans error checking its something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) 
{
    struct point *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    p->x = p->y = i;
    enqueue(q, p);
    printf("One node added, front value: %i, back value: %i\n", 
        ((struct point*)peek_front(q))->x, ((struct point*)peek_back(q))->x);
}


while (q->size > 0) {
    struct point *p = dequeue(q);
    printf("One node removed, value = (%i,%i). Size is now %i \n", p->x, p->y, q->size);
    free(p); // NOTE, freeing the dynamic memory we allocated during insertion.
}

free(q);
```

**Output**

```
One node added, front value: 1, back value: 1
One node added, front value: 1, back value: 2
One node added, front value: 1, back value: 3
One node removed, value = (1,1). Size is now 2
One node removed, value = (2,2). Size is now 1
One node removed, value = (3,3). Size is now 0
```